# WPF MVVM: how to bind GridViewColumn to ViewModel-Collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

In my View I got a ListView bound to a CollectionView in my ViewModel, for example like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true">
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridViewColumn Header="Title" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
      <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
      <GridViewColumn Header="Phone" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Phone}"/>
      <GridViewColumn Header="E-mail" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=EMail}"/>
    </GridView>
  </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Right now these GridViewColumns are fixed, but I'd like to be able to change them from the ViewModel. I'd guess I'll have to bind the GridViewColumn-collection to something in the ViewModel, but what, and how?
The ViewModel does know nothing of WPF, so I got no clue how to achieve this in MVVM.

any help here?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The `Columns` property is not a dependency property, so you can't bind it. However, it might be possible to create an attached property that you could bind to a collection in your ViewModel. This attached property would then create the columns for you.

---

UPDATE

OK, here's a basic implementation...

**Attached properties**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace TestPadWPF
{
    public static class GridViewColumns
    {
        [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(GridView))]
        public static object GetColumnsSource(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (object)obj.GetValue(ColumnsSourceProperty);
        }

        public static void SetColumnsSource(DependencyObject obj, object value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(ColumnsSourceProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ColumnsSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "ColumnsSource",
                typeof(object),
                typeof(GridViewColumns),
                new UIPropertyMetadata(
                    null,
                    ColumnsSourceChanged));


        [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(GridView))]
        public static string GetHeaderTextMember(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (string)obj.GetValue(HeaderTextMemberProperty);
        }

        public static void SetHeaderTextMember(DependencyObject obj, string value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(HeaderTextMemberProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HeaderTextMember.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderTextMemberProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HeaderTextMember", typeof(string), typeof(GridViewColumns), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));


        [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(GridView))]
        public static string GetDisplayMemberMember(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (string)obj.GetValue(DisplayMemberMemberProperty);
        }

        public static void SetDisplayMemberMember(DependencyObject obj, string value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(DisplayMemberMemberProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for DisplayMember.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayMemberMemberProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DisplayMemberMember", typeof(string), typeof(GridViewColumns), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));


        private static void ColumnsSourceChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView gridView = obj as GridView;
            if (gridView != null)
            {
                gridView.Columns.Clear();

                if (e.OldValue != null)
                {
                    ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(e.OldValue);
                    if (view != null)
                        RemoveHandlers(gridView, view);
                }

                if (e.NewValue != null)
                {
                    ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(e.NewValue);
                    if (view != null)
                    {
                        AddHandlers(gridView, view);
                        CreateColumns(gridView, view);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static IDictionary<ICollectionView, List<GridView>> _gridViewsByColumnsSource =
            new Dictionary<ICollectionView, List<GridView>>();

        private static List<GridView> GetGridViewsForColumnSource(ICollectionView columnSource)
        {
            List<GridView> gridViews;
            if (!_gridViewsByColumnsSource.TryGetValue(columnSource, out gridViews))
            {
                gridViews = new List<GridView>();
                _gridViewsByColumnsSource.Add(columnSource, gridViews);
            }
            return gridViews;
        }

        private static void AddHandlers(GridView gridView, ICollectionView view)
        {
            GetGridViewsForColumnSource(view).Add(gridView);
            view.CollectionChanged += ColumnsSource_CollectionChanged;
        }

        private static void CreateColumns(GridView gridView, ICollectionView view)
        {
            foreach (var item in view)
            {
                GridViewColumn column = CreateColumn(gridView, item);
                gridView.Columns.Add(column);
            }
        }

        private static void RemoveHandlers(GridView gridView, ICollectionView view)
        {
            view.CollectionChanged -= ColumnsSource_CollectionChanged;
            GetGridViewsForColumnSource(view).Remove(gridView);
        }

        private static void ColumnsSource_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ICollectionView view = sender as ICollectionView;
            var gridViews = GetGridViewsForColumnSource(view);
            if (gridViews == null || gridViews.Count == 0)
                return;

            switch (e.Action)
            {
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                    foreach (var gridView in gridViews)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < e.NewItems.Count; i++)
                        {
                            GridViewColumn column = CreateColumn(gridView, e.NewItems[i]);
                            gridView.Columns.Insert(e.NewStartingIndex + i, column);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                    foreach (var gridView in gridViews)
                    {
                        List<GridViewColumn> columns = new List<GridViewColumn>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < e.OldItems.Count; i++)
                        {
                            GridViewColumn column = gridView.Columns[e.OldStartingIndex + i];
                            columns.Add(column);
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < e.NewItems.Count; i++)
                        {
                            GridViewColumn column = columns[i];
                            gridView.Columns.Insert(e.NewStartingIndex + i, column);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                    foreach (var gridView in gridViews)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < e.OldItems.Count; i++)
                        {
                            gridView.Columns.RemoveAt(e.OldStartingIndex);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                    foreach (var gridView in gridViews)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < e.NewItems.Count; i++)
                        {
                            GridViewColumn column = CreateColumn(gridView, e.NewItems[i]);
                            gridView.Columns[e.NewStartingIndex + i] = column;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                    foreach (var gridView in gridViews)
                    {
                        gridView.Columns.Clear();
                        CreateColumns(gridView, sender as ICollectionView);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        private static GridViewColumn CreateColumn(GridView gridView, object columnSource)
        {
            GridViewColumn column = new GridViewColumn();
            string headerTextMember = GetHeaderTextMember(gridView);
            string displayMemberMember = GetDisplayMemberMember(gridView);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerTextMember))
            {
                column.Header = GetPropertyValue(columnSource, headerTextMember);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayMemberMember))
            {
                string propertyName = GetPropertyValue(columnSource, displayMemberMember) as string;
                column.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(propertyName);
            }
            return column;
        }

        private static object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyName)
        {
            if (obj != null)
            {
                PropertyInfo prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
                if (prop != null)
                    return prop.GetValue(obj, null);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class PersonsViewModel
{
    public PersonsViewModel()
    {
        this.Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>
        {
            new Person
            {
                Name = "Doe",
                FirstName = "John",
                DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1981, 9, 12)
            },
            new Person
            {
                Name = "Black",
                FirstName = "Jack",
                DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1950, 1, 15)
            },
            new Person
            {
                Name = "Smith",
                FirstName = "Jane",
                DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1987, 7, 23)
            }
        };

        this.Columns = new ObservableCollection<ColumnDescriptor>
        {
            new ColumnDescriptor { HeaderText = "Last name", DisplayMember = "Name" },
            new ColumnDescriptor { HeaderText = "First name", DisplayMember = "FirstName" },
            new ColumnDescriptor { HeaderText = "Date of birth", DisplayMember = "DateOfBirth" }
        };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; private set; }

    public ObservableCollection<ColumnDescriptor> Columns { get; private set; }

    private ICommand _addColumnCommand;
    public ICommand AddColumnCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_addColumnCommand == null)
            {
                _addColumnCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(
                    s =>
                    {
                        this.Columns.Add(new ColumnDescriptor { HeaderText = s, DisplayMember = s });
                    });
            }
            return _addColumnCommand;
        }
    }

    private ICommand _removeColumnCommand;
    public ICommand RemoveColumnCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_removeColumnCommand == null)
            {
                _removeColumnCommand = new DelegateCommand<string>(
                    s =>
                    {
                        this.Columns.Remove(this.Columns.FirstOrDefault(d => d.DisplayMember == s));
                    });
            }
            return _removeColumnCommand;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML :

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" Grid.Row="0">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView local:GridViewColumns.HeaderTextMember="HeaderText"
                      local:GridViewColumns.DisplayMemberMember="DisplayMember"
                      local:GridViewColumns.ColumnsSource="{Binding Columns}"/>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Note that the `ColumnDescriptor` class is not actually needed, I only added it for clarity, but any type will do (including an anonymous type). You just need to specify which properties hold the header text and display member name.

Also, keep in mind that it's not fully tested yet, so there might be a few problems to fix...

Comment: Uhm, I'm not really sure I understand how to achieve your suggestion.

Comment: Wow, great, thanks! I'm checking it out, you did not add the declaration of ColumnDescriptor, but as you say, it should be easy to create.  
I'll notify as soon as I understand it at least a bit more ;)

Comment: Cool, works like expected, great! Thanks a lot for the thorough example!

Comment: Great example! I copy/pasted your sample code into a different project, and it worked like a charm, thanks!

Comment: +1 sucks that it has to be this way but this worked perfectly.

Comment: Here the person class is predefined. How we can approach if we need more than 3 fields in the Person Class

Comment: @Csharp_crack I don't understand what you're asking... Could you elaborate?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque In your person class you have 3 fields which you have defined already and you duly assign them as display members. How to do if the number of columns itself is dynamic and it may vary on runtime

Comment: @ThomasLevesque [Here's my actual problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48971769/wpf-datagrid-flickering-issue). I'm trying with Listview/Gridview instead of Datagrid. Please help me if you can

Comment: @Csharp_crack well, at some point you will need to know which fields you want to display. If the data type isn't known statically, you could use reflection and create a `ColumnDescriptor` for each property.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasLevesque. Even i thought of reflection, such as is my issue. Can you look at the above link i have pasted. It will be of great help if provide any suggestions

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Old answer for sure - but could you please elaborate a litte bit on the purpose and why we need the _gridViewByColumnSource dictionary? Could we not just work with the gridView.Columns collection directly?

Answer (score 10):

I took Thomas Levesque's excellent solution and modified it to remove the static collection of GridViews and also add the ability to set a column width and string format, so thought I'd share my code.

Modified attached property class:

```
public static class GridViewColumnCollection
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnCollectionBehaviourProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ColumnCollectionBehaviour", typeof(GridViewColumnCollectionBehaviour), typeof(GridViewColumnCollection), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ColumnsSource", typeof(object), typeof(GridViewColumnCollection), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, GridViewColumnCollection.ColumnsSourceChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayMemberFormatMemberProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DisplayMemberFormatMember", typeof(string), typeof(GridViewColumnCollection), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, GridViewColumnCollection.DisplayMemberFormatMemberChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayMemberMemberProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DisplayMemberMember", typeof(string), typeof(GridViewColumnCollection), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, GridViewColumnCollection.DisplayMemberMemberChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderTextMemberProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HeaderTextMember", typeof(string), typeof(GridViewColumnCollection), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, GridViewColumnCollection.HeaderTextMemberChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty WidthMemberProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("WidthMember", typeof(string), typeof(GridViewColumnCollection), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, GridViewColumnCollection.WidthMemberChanged));

    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(GridView))]
    public static GridViewColumnCollectionBehaviour GetColumnCollectionBehaviour(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (GridViewColumnCollectionBehaviour)obj.GetValue(ColumnCollectionBehaviourProperty);
    }

    public static void SetColumnCollectionBehaviour(DependencyObject obj, GridViewColumnCollectionBehaviour value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ColumnCollectionBehaviourProperty, value);
    }

    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(GridView))]
    public static object GetColumnsSource(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (object)obj.GetValue(ColumnsSourceProperty);
    }

    public static void SetColumnsSource(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ColumnsSourceProperty, value);
    }

    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(GridView))]
    public static string GetDisplayMemberFormatMember(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(DisplayMemberFormatMemberProperty);
    }

    public static void SetDisplayMemberFormatMember(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(DisplayMemberFormatMemberProperty, value);
    }

    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(GridView))]
    public static string GetDisplayMemberMember(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(DisplayMemberMemberProperty);
    }

    public static void SetDisplayMemberMember(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(DisplayMemberMemberProperty, value);
    }

    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(GridView))]
    public static string GetHeaderTextMember(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(HeaderTextMemberProperty);
    }

    public static void SetHeaderTextMember(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(HeaderTextMemberProperty, value);
    }

    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(GridView))]
    public static string GetWidthMember(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(WidthMemberProperty);
    }

    public static void SetWidthMember(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(WidthMemberProperty, value);
    }

    private static void ColumnsSourceChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewColumnCollection.GetOrCreateColumnCollectionBehaviour(sender).ColumnsSource = e.NewValue;
    }

    private static void DisplayMemberFormatMemberChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewColumnCollection.GetOrCreateColumnCollectionBehaviour(sender).DisplayMemberFormatMember = e.NewValue as string;
    }

    private static void DisplayMemberMemberChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewColumnCollection.GetOrCreateColumnCollectionBehaviour(sender).DisplayMemberMember = e.NewValue as string;
    }

    private static void HeaderTextMemberChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewColumnCollection.GetOrCreateColumnCollectionBehaviour(sender).HeaderTextMember = e.NewValue as string;
    }

    private static void WidthMemberChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewColumnCollection.GetOrCreateColumnCollectionBehaviour(sender).WidthMember = e.NewValue as string;
    }

    private static GridViewColumnCollectionBehaviour GetOrCreateColumnCollectionBehaviour(DependencyObject source)
    {
        GridViewColumnCollectionBehaviour behaviour = GetColumnCollectionBehaviour(source);

        if (behaviour == null)
        {
            GridView typedSource = source as GridView;

            if (typedSource == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("This property can only be set on controls deriving GridView");
            }

            behaviour = new GridViewColumnCollectionBehaviour(typedSource);

            SetColumnCollectionBehaviour(typedSource, behaviour);
        }

        return behaviour;
    }
}
```

Behaviour (this is stored against each GridView and obviates the need to store the collection-GridView mappings centrally):

```
public class GridViewColumnCollectionBehaviour
{
    private object columnsSource;
    private GridView gridView;

    public GridViewColumnCollectionBehaviour(GridView gridView)
    {
        this.gridView = gridView;
    }

    public object ColumnsSource
    {
        get { return this.columnsSource; }
        set
        {
            object oldValue = this.columnsSource;
            this.columnsSource = value;
            this.ColumnsSourceChanged(oldValue, this.columnsSource);
        }
    }

    public string DisplayMemberFormatMember { get; set; }

    public string DisplayMemberMember { get; set; }

    public string HeaderTextMember { get; set; }

    public string WidthMember { get; set; }

    private void AddHandlers(ICollectionView collectionView)
    {
        collectionView.CollectionChanged += this.ColumnsSource_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void ColumnsSource_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ICollectionView view = sender as ICollectionView;

        if (this.gridView == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                for (int i = 0; i < e.NewItems.Count; i++)
                {
                    GridViewColumn column = CreateColumn(e.NewItems[i]);
                    gridView.Columns.Insert(e.NewStartingIndex + i, column);
                }
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                List<GridViewColumn> columns = new List<GridViewColumn>();

                for (int i = 0; i < e.OldItems.Count; i++)
                {
                    GridViewColumn column = gridView.Columns[e.OldStartingIndex + i];
                    columns.Add(column);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < e.NewItems.Count; i++)
                {
                    GridViewColumn column = columns[i];
                    gridView.Columns.Insert(e.NewStartingIndex + i, column);
                }
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                for (int i = 0; i < e.OldItems.Count; i++)
                {
                    gridView.Columns.RemoveAt(e.OldStartingIndex);
                }
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                for (int i = 0; i < e.NewItems.Count; i++)
                {
                    GridViewColumn column = CreateColumn(e.NewItems[i]);

                    gridView.Columns[e.NewStartingIndex + i] = column;
                }
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                gridView.Columns.Clear();
                CreateColumns(sender as ICollectionView);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void ColumnsSourceChanged(object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if (this.gridView != null)
        {
            gridView.Columns.Clear();

            if (oldValue != null)
            {
                ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(oldValue);

                if (view != null)
                {
                    this.RemoveHandlers(view);
                }
            }

            if (newValue != null)
            {
                ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(newValue);

                if (view != null)
                {
                    this.AddHandlers(view);

                    this.CreateColumns(view);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private GridViewColumn CreateColumn(object columnSource)
    {
        GridViewColumn column = new GridViewColumn();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.HeaderTextMember))
        {
            column.Header = GetPropertyValue(columnSource, this.HeaderTextMember);
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.DisplayMemberMember))
        {
            string propertyName = GetPropertyValue(columnSource, this.DisplayMemberMember) as string;

            string format = null;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.DisplayMemberFormatMember))
            {
                format = GetPropertyValue(columnSource, this.DisplayMemberFormatMember) as string;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(format))
            {
                format = "{0}";
            }

            column.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding(propertyName) { StringFormat = format };
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.WidthMember))
        {
            double width = (double)GetPropertyValue(columnSource, this.WidthMember);
            column.Width = width;
        }

        return column;
    }

    private void CreateColumns(ICollectionView collectionView)
    {
        foreach (object item in collectionView)
        {
            GridViewColumn column = this.CreateColumn(item);

            this.gridView.Columns.Add(column);
        }
    }

    private object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyName)
    {
        object returnVal = null;

        if (obj != null)
        {
            PropertyInfo prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);

            if (prop != null)
            {
                returnVal = prop.GetValue(obj, null);
            }
        }

        return returnVal;
    }

    private void RemoveHandlers(ICollectionView collectionView)
    {
        collectionView.CollectionChanged -= this.ColumnsSource_CollectionChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: What about cell templates?

Comment: If you want to set other properties on the created GridViewColumns then modify the attached behaviour class to include the new properties and modify the behaviour class (in particular CreateColumn) accordingly. To get started, try looking at what happens when a property value changes on the attached behaviour class (e.g. WidthMember) and follow it through from there.

Answer (score 2):

I think this code would cause some memory leak issues; As your class GridViewColumns described, you've defined a static dictionary "_gridViewsByColumnsSource" in which contains the gridviews and their columns source references; so this is a strong reference to the added gridviews and columns source; Because this dictionary is static, it seems that there's a static reference "point" to the gridviews and columns source data all the time, if the screen in which the gridview defined closed, the gridview cannot be collected by GC if GC is started; As more and more similar screens opened, more and more gridviews and its columns source data cannot be collected, there'll be memory leak at the end.

Comment: I confirmed this problem with a memory profiler. You could remedy this by setting ColumnsSource to null when your control is disposed, which should cause the reference to be removed (in the RemoveHandlers method), or change _gridViewsByColumnsSource to hold a list of WeakReference objects and implement a weak event listener for the ICollectionView.CollectionChanged event.

Comment: Actually you wouldn't need a weak event listener...just a WeakReference to the GridView.

Comment: How do you fix the memory leak ? This is the original code `private static IDictionary<ICollectionView, List<GridView>> _gridViewsByColumnsSource = new Dictionary<ICollectionView, List<GridView>>();`