# ListView or DataGridView

Tags: c#, wpf

Being new to WPF I am looking for guidance on which control would be best to use for the following scenario.

I need to create an application which displays two lists side by side. The list on the left displays a list of users. The list on the right displays a list of permissions.

I want to be able to dynamically add/remove a column of check boxes indicating the user permissions to the right hand permission list by clicking/dragging users from the left hand list. The number of user permission columns will be from 0 - total number of users. The check box should bind to the underlying data i.e. update the users permission.

Which control should I use to achieve the right hand permission list, a ListView or DataGrid?

I have something working by using a ListView and creating an attached property using the following answer as a guide [WPF MVVM: how to bind GridViewColumn to ViewModel-Collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643545/wpf-mvvm-how-to-bind-gridviewcolumn-to-viewmodel-collection) but this doesn't render a checkbox only true/false for the permission status. Looking into how to dynamically add a CellDataTemplate to render a checkbox has made me question whether I should be using a DataGrid.

If I was to use a DataGrid how would the dynamic addition of columns work?

I would like to keep the code behind to a minimum if at all possible.

Comment: You should be able to accomplish what you want with both. Its just a matter of which one you like the look of.

Comment: As @CathalMF said you can do most w/ both. Ask yourself if you really need data-grid specifics - e.g. columns, sorting by it, grouping, adding etc. If you just have an 'agnostic' view ListView is fine. You can style item template - or use data templates to present different types - and add checkbox for 'boolean'. On the other side, grid can handle dynamic columns nicely (from code behind only - but not a big deal), and you can also style each cell type / column.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance on your question, I thought a Datagrid would be a better choice. I'm a vb.net guy but I think the syntax would be very similar

To add columns at runtime the code behind looks like this

```
DataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column Name", "Column Heading")
```

You could always just do a google search on "Adding columns to a DataGrid at runtime in C#" and that should return a bunch of examples.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, The actual syntax for the addition of the column as you rightly point out is easily obtainable via a google search. But my problem, which granted probably wasn't clear in the question, is how would I construct the view model so I can dynamically bind the columns to the DataGridView. The number of permissions and users can change and both are > 1000 so binding to a dataset containing the whole grid seemed bad given the potential size of the grid but hey maybe I am wrong on that front.