# Grid View Dynamic column headers WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

How do I create a grid view with dynamic column headers by binding the data from ViewModel?

I am trying to created a grid like this.

```
Id --- Name --- [Name of games played "other detail I will get from the model"]
```

For example if I have played 5 games I have to create a grid with a header like the following

```
Id -- Name ---- Soccer -- Tennis ---Golf ----- Cricket --- Polo
```

How can I achieve this using MVVM binding in XAML? Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF MVVM: how to bind GridViewColumn to ViewModel-Collection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643545/wpf-mvvm-how-to-bind-gridviewcolumn-to-viewmodel-collection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is possibly a duplicate of [WPF MVVM: how to bind GridViewColumn to ViewModel-Collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643545/wpf-mvvm-how-to-bind-gridviewcolumn-to-viewmodel-collection)

You might want to look into this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2644202/4317569

Comment: Need some more information .. How do we achieve columnspan ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? GridView does not support spanning columns. Could you make an example?

Comment: i have one set of data which has an id , name , telephone No. each id has telephone numbers (like home and work numbers). so id and name has to be having a colspan of two and the next column will have home number in first row and work number in second row

Comment: i have picture but here i couldnt post .. i should get 10 reputation :(