# WPF Binding a GridView when that bound data contains a list

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, mvvm

Background: I want to display a list of items of stock in a GridView.  Easy enough.  However, each stock item has a list of prices associated it.  Currently I'm using 5 possible price lists, however, the number of price lists is not set and could be any number (within reason).  I want to display those prices in the Grid View in separate columns.  I'm dynamically generating columns in the grid view (based on what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643545/wpf-mvvm-how-to-bind-gridviewcolumn-to-viewmodel-collection), the second example posted by Dan Parsonson).  However, I cannot figure out how I would bind to a List within an ObservableCollection.  I've been searching for some time but I'm yet to find anything that seems relevant to this situation.

Greatly reduced StockItem definition:

```
public class StockItem
{
    public string StockCode { get; set; }
    public int StockToHand { get; set; }
    public List<ListPrice> Prices { get; set; }
}
```

ListPrice simply contains a string for the Name and a Decimal for the Price.

I add the columns to the grid view like this:

```
private void UpdateColumns()
{
    ObservableCollection<ColumnDescriptor> columns = new ObservableCollection<ColumnDescriptor>();
    columns.Add(new ColumnDescriptor 
                { HeaderText = "Stock Code", DisplayMember = "StockCode" });
    columns.Add(new ColumnDescriptor 
                { HeaderText = "Stock To Hand", DisplayMember = "StockToHand" });

    // Add price list columns
    List<PriceList> priceLists = GetPriceLists();
    foreach(PriceList pl in priceLists)
    {
        colums.Add(new ColumnDescriptor
                   { HeaderText = pl.Name, DisplayMember = "Prices.Price" });
    }
    GridViewColumns = columns;
}
```

GetPriceLists() just grabs all the price lists defined in the database so I can name the columns for all the possible price lists.  ColumnDescriptor is just a simple class for containing the column name and the path to the display member.  GridViewColumns is where the GridView looks to get its columns.

XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentStockItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStockItem}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView Helpers:GridViewColumnCollection.DisplayMemberMember="DisplayMember" 
                  Helpers:GridViewColumnCollection.HeaderTextMember="HeaderText"
                  Helpers:GridViewColumnCollection.ColumnsSource="{Binding GridViewColumns}"/>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Ultimately I'm looking for a GridView that looks a bit like this:

```
+----------+-------------+------------+------------+
|Stock Code|Stock To Hand|List 1 Price|List 2 Price|
+----------+-------------+------------+------------+
|  12345   |      1      |   45.95    |   40.23    |
+----------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

Where the last 2 (or however many columns) are generated from information in a List, or some other collection, and each row in the GridView is contained by 1 object (e.g. the StockItem class posted above).

I was hoping (wildly) that putting `DisplayMember = "Prices.Price"` (in the second code block) would invoke some sort of WPF magic to get the data into the GridView but, unfortunately, I see no data in the GridView.  I obviously need to do more to get the data across to the view but after a lot of searching I can't find an obvious solution.

Comment: You could (should) add those columns to your ViewModels and let the View use auto-generated or fixed columns.

Comment: I don't think GridView can autogenerate columns and fixed columns are not appropriate because the number of columns will vary.

Comment: To clarify, UpdateColumns is part of the view model.

Comment: Ok...I get it guys...I'm an idiot...turns out that DisplayMember = "Prices[" + priceLists.IndexOf(pl) +  "].Price" works.  Now I know that works (no idea why I didn't try it sooner) I can figure out how to make it more robust.

Answer (score 0):

I figured I should answer this myself because I figured it out and realised I was being a bit derpy.  The following:

```
foreach(PriceList pl in priceLists)
{
    colums.Add(new ColumnDescriptor
               { HeaderText = pl.Name, DisplayMember = "Prices.Price" });
}
```

Can be changed to:

```
foreach(PriceList pl in priceLists)
{
    columns.Add(new ColumnDescriptor 
               { HeaderText = pl.Name, 
                 DisplayMember = "Prices[" + priceLists.IndexOf(pl) +  "].Price" });
}
```

It's not yet perfect but I had no idea I could use an index in a binding like that and don't think I've seen it anywhere else on the internets!

If this solution is not ideal for any reason then feel free to point it out/correct me.