# WPF: MVVM Binding Two Dimensional Collection to GridView

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, mvvm

I'm looking for a way to bind a two dimensional collection to a `ListView` `GridView`.  So far I have been able to bind my data to nested `ItemsControl` controls that look like a grid.  However I would like it to behave like a `GridView` where the columns can be resized by the user.

The view model looks like this:

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace BindingTest
{
    public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> ColumnHeaders 
        {
            get { return _columnHeaders; } 
            set
            {
                if (_columnHeaders == value)
                    return;

                _columnHeaders = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => ColumnHeaders);
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<object>> Data
        {
            get { return _data; }
            set
            {
                if (_data == value)
                    return;

                _data = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Data);
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<string> _columnHeaders;
        private ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<object>> _data;

        public ViewModel()
        {
            ColumnHeaders = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            ColumnHeaders.Add("String Column");
            ColumnHeaders.Add("Boolean Column");

            Data = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<object>>();

            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                ObservableCollection<object> row = new ObservableCollection<object>();
                row.Add("cell " + i);
                row.Add(i % 2 == 0 ? true : false);

                Data.Add(row);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The inner collection in `Data` can contain any type of objects and there can be any number of columns.  I also need to be able to use different `DataTemplate` to render each cell depending on the object type.

My current view xaml looks like the following:

```
<UserControl x:Class="BindingTest.View"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:clr="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             DataContext="{Binding ViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="StringDataTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ColumnHeaders}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Width="100" Text="{Binding }"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}">
                                            <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                                                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type clr:String}">
                                                    <TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding Path=.}"/>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type clr:Boolean}">
                                                    <CheckBox Width="100" IsChecked="{Binding Path=.}"/>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type clr:DateTime}">
                                                    <DatePicker Width="100" SelectedDate="{Binding Path=.}"/>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                                        </ContentPresenter>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

I would like to use a `GridView` on my `ListView` but I can't quite figure out how to bind to my data in a MVVM manner.

Comment: Could you provide the VM and a method that returns it with some sample data I can use for testing. Sorry feeling a bit lazy to reverse engineer atm

Comment: I have updated my question to include the full view and view model code.  Please note I'm using MVVM Light.

Comment: @Kurorion please look at the next solution it is a good starting point to your question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643545/wpf-mvvm-how-to-bind-gridviewcolumn-to-viewmodel-collection. Let me know if you will have problems with the code.

Comment: @Ilan Thanks for pointing out Dan Parsonson's solution.  But I'm not really sure how to implement it.  Are you able to provide a short example of the implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try the next solution. All credits to guys which provided us with solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643545/wpf-mvvm-how-to-bind-gridviewcolumn-to-viewmodel-collection). So I've tried to match your question to solution of guys in the link behind.

**XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFAddGridViewColumnDynamicHelpAttempt.BindingTest"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:clr="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         xmlns:wpfAddGridViewColumnDynamicHelpAttempt="clr-namespace:WPFAddGridViewColumnDynamicHelpAttempt"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <wpfAddGridViewColumnDynamicHelpAttempt:ViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<ListView x:Name="ListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" Grid.Row="0">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView wpfAddGridViewColumnDynamicHelpAttempt:GridViewColumns.HeaderTextMember="HeaderText"
                  wpfAddGridViewColumnDynamicHelpAttempt:GridViewColumns.Parent="{Binding ElementName=ListView}"
                  wpfAddGridViewColumnDynamicHelpAttempt:GridViewColumns.DisplayMemberMember="DisplayMember"
                  wpfAddGridViewColumnDynamicHelpAttempt:GridViewColumns.ColumnTemplateKey="ColumnTemplateTemplateKey"
                  wpfAddGridViewColumnDynamicHelpAttempt:GridViewColumns.ColumnsSource="{Binding ColumnHeaders}">
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView></UserControl>
```

**ViewModel and models (please see comments)**

```
public class ViewModel : BaseObservableObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<ColumnDescriptor> ColumnHeaders
    {
        get { return _columnHeaders; }
        set
        {
            if (_columnHeaders == value)
                return;

            _columnHeaders = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => ColumnHeaders);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Data
    {
        get { return _data; }
        set
        {
            if (_data == value)
                return;

            _data = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => Data);
        }
    }

    //here I've changed the column object from string to ColumnDescriptor object,
    //to match the values defined in AttachedPropeties (GridViewColumns class)
    //please keep in mind that every colun is binded to data in model, thus if your model 
    //won't have property named Salary, but your ColumnHeaders collection will have the ColumnDescriptor 
    //with that DisplayMember you will have binding expression exception in output window.
    //So you have define ColumnHeaders collection with certain number of ColumnDescriptors (as you want to display by model).
    private ObservableCollection<ColumnDescriptor> _columnHeaders;

    //since the Data is binded to the listview that give its ItemsSource to the GridView,
    //we don't have to have an ObservableCollection of ObservableCollections of objects, we can provide the actual values and 
    //they will be distrebuted to presented columns
    private ObservableCollection<Person> _data;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        ColumnHeaders = new ObservableCollection<ColumnDescriptor>
        {
            new ColumnDescriptor {HeaderText = "Last name", DisplayMember = "LastName", ColumnTemplateTemplateKey = typeof(String)},
            new ColumnDescriptor {HeaderText = "First name", DisplayMember = "FirstName", ColumnTemplateTemplateKey = typeof(String)},
            new ColumnDescriptor {HeaderText = "Salary", DisplayMember = "Salary", ColumnTemplateTemplateKey = typeof(String)},
            new ColumnDescriptor {HeaderText = "Date Of Birth", DisplayMember = "DateOfBirth", ColumnTemplateTemplateKey = typeof(DateTime)},
            new ColumnDescriptor {HeaderText = "Gift Was Delivered", DisplayMember = "GiftWasDelivered", ColumnTemplateTemplateKey = typeof(Boolean)},
        };

        Data = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Data = new ObservableCollection<Person>
            {
                new Person {FirstName = "John", LastName = "A.", DateOfBirth=new DateTime(1965, 12, 1), GiftWasDelivered = false},
                new Person {FirstName = "Ron", LastName = "B.", DateOfBirth=new DateTime(1995, 6, 8), GiftWasDelivered = false}
            };
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// defines the column data (column heder text and column content)
/// </summary>
public class ColumnDescriptor
{
    /// <summary>
    /// defines the actual text that will be shown in the grid view column header
    /// </summary>
    public string HeaderText { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// defines the name of the property in view model that will be presented by this column
    /// </summary>
    public string DisplayMember { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// defines the key of thew template
    /// </summary>
    public object ColumnTemplateTemplateKey { get; set; }
}

public class Person:BaseObservableObject
{
    private string _name;
    private string _lastName;
    private DateTime _dateOfBirth;
    private bool _giftWasDelivered;

    public bool GiftWasDelivered
    {
        get { return _giftWasDelivered; }
        set
        {
            _giftWasDelivered = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _lastName; }
        set
        {
            _lastName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public DateTime DateOfBirth
    {
        get { return _dateOfBirth; }
        set
        {
            _dateOfBirth = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Adapted Attached propertis from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643545/wpf-mvvm-how-to-bind-gridviewcolumn-to-viewmodel-collection), use this as a black box solution**

```
public static class GridViewColumns
{
    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(GridView))]
    public static object GetColumnsSource(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (object)obj.GetValue(ColumnsSourceProperty);
    }

    public static void SetColumnsSource(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ColumnsSourceProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ColumnsSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "ColumnsSource",
            typeof(object),
            typeof(GridViewColumns),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(
                null,
                ColumnsSourceChanged));


    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(GridView))]
    public static string GetHeaderTextMember(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(HeaderTextMemberProperty);
    }

    public static void SetHeaderTextMember(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(HeaderTextMemberProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HeaderTextMember.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderTextMemberProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HeaderTextMember", typeof(string), typeof(GridViewColumns), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));


    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(GridView))]
    public static string GetDisplayMemberMember(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(DisplayMemberMemberProperty);
    }

    public static void SetDisplayMemberMember(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(DisplayMemberMemberProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for DisplayMember.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayMemberMemberProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DisplayMemberMember", typeof(string), typeof(GridViewColumns), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));


    private static void ColumnsSourceChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gridView = obj as GridView;
        if (gridView != null)
        {
            gridView.Columns.Clear();

            if (e.OldValue != null)
            {
                ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(e.OldValue);
                if (view != null)
                    RemoveHandlers(gridView, view);
            }

            if (e.NewValue != null)
            {
                ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(e.NewValue);
                if (view != null)
                {
                    AddHandlers(gridView, view);
                    CreateColumns(gridView, view);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static IDictionary<ICollectionView, List<GridView>> _gridViewsByColumnsSource =
        new Dictionary<ICollectionView, List<GridView>>();

    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(GridView))]
    public static string GetColumnTemplateKey(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (string)element.GetValue(ColumnTemplateKeyProperty);
    }

    public static void SetColumnTemplateKey(DependencyObject element, string value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ColumnTemplateKeyProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnTemplateKeyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ColumnTemplateKey", typeof (string), typeof (GridViewColumns),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public static object GetParent(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (object)element.GetValue(ParentProperty);
    }

    public static void SetParent(DependencyObject element, object value)
    {
        element.SetValue(ParentProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ParentProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Parent",
        typeof (object), typeof (GridViewColumns), new PropertyMetadata(default(object)));

    private static List<GridView> GetGridViewsForColumnSource(ICollectionView columnSource)
    {
        List<GridView> gridViews;
        if (!_gridViewsByColumnsSource.TryGetValue(columnSource, out gridViews))
        {
            gridViews = new List<GridView>();
            _gridViewsByColumnsSource.Add(columnSource, gridViews);
        }
        return gridViews;
    }

    private static void AddHandlers(GridView gridView, ICollectionView view)
    {
        GetGridViewsForColumnSource(view).Add(gridView);
        view.CollectionChanged += ColumnsSource_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private static void CreateColumns(GridView gridView, ICollectionView view)
    {
        foreach (var item in view)
        {
            GridViewColumn column = CreateColumn(gridView, item);
            gridView.Columns.Add(column);
        }
    }

    private static void RemoveHandlers(GridView gridView, ICollectionView view)
    {
        view.CollectionChanged -= ColumnsSource_CollectionChanged;
        GetGridViewsForColumnSource(view).Remove(gridView);
    }

    private static void ColumnsSource_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ICollectionView view = sender as ICollectionView;
        var gridViews = GetGridViewsForColumnSource(view);
        if (gridViews == null || gridViews.Count == 0)
            return;

        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                foreach (var gridView in gridViews)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < e.NewItems.Count; i++)
                    {
                        GridViewColumn column = CreateColumn(gridView, e.NewItems[i]);
                        gridView.Columns.Insert(e.NewStartingIndex + i, column);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                foreach (var gridView in gridViews)
                {
                    List<GridViewColumn> columns = new List<GridViewColumn>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < e.OldItems.Count; i++)
                    {
                        GridViewColumn column = gridView.Columns[e.OldStartingIndex + i];
                        columns.Add(column);
                    }
                    for (int i = 0; i < e.NewItems.Count; i++)
                    {
                        GridViewColumn column = columns[i];
                        gridView.Columns.Insert(e.NewStartingIndex + i, column);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                foreach (var gridView in gridViews)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < e.OldItems.Count; i++)
                    {
                        gridView.Columns.RemoveAt(e.OldStartingIndex);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                foreach (var gridView in gridViews)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < e.NewItems.Count; i++)
                    {
                        GridViewColumn column = CreateColumn(gridView, e.NewItems[i]);
                        gridView.Columns[e.NewStartingIndex + i] = column;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                foreach (var gridView in gridViews)
                {
                    gridView.Columns.Clear();
                    CreateColumns(gridView, sender as ICollectionView);
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    //here we create columns and define theire binding,
    //in addition we can create (or find) data template for each columns
    private static GridViewColumn CreateColumn(GridView gridView, object columnSource)
    {
        GridViewColumn column = new GridViewColumn();
        string headerTextMember = GetHeaderTextMember(gridView);
        string displayMemberMember = GetDisplayMemberMember(gridView);
        string templateKey = GetColumnTemplateKey(gridView);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerTextMember))
        {
            column.Header = GetPropertyValue(columnSource, headerTextMember);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(templateKey))
        {
            DefineSimpleCustomDataTemplateWithBinding(columnSource, templateKey, displayMemberMember, column);
        }
        else
        {
            DefineDefaultBinding(columnSource, displayMemberMember, column);
        }
        return column;
    }

    private static void DefineSimpleCustomDataTemplateWithBinding(object columnSource, string templateKey, string displayMemberMember,
        GridViewColumn column)
    {
        var keyType = GetPropertyValue(columnSource, templateKey) as Type;
        if (keyType == null)
        {
            DefineDefaultBinding(columnSource, displayMemberMember, column);
        }
        else
        {
            var propertyName = GetPropertyValue(columnSource, displayMemberMember) as string;
            var binding = new Binding(propertyName) {FallbackValue = "data is not presented by provided model"};
            var dataTemplate = DataTemplateFactory.GetDataTemplateWithBindingByType(keyType, binding);
            if (dataTemplate == null)
            {
                DefineDefaultBinding(columnSource, displayMemberMember, column);
            }
            else
            {
                column.CellTemplate = dataTemplate;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void DefineDefaultBinding(object columnSource, string displayMemberMember, GridViewColumn column)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(displayMemberMember))
        {
            string propertyName = GetPropertyValue(columnSource, displayMemberMember) as string;
            var binding = new Binding(propertyName) {FallbackValue = "data is not presented by provided model"};
            column.DisplayMemberBinding = binding;
        }
    }

    private static object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyName)
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            PropertyInfo prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
            if (prop != null)
                return prop.GetValue(obj, null);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Factory to create data template in code (create your own as you need)**

```
    /// <summary>
/// helps to define simple data template in code
/// </summary>
public class DataTemplateFactory
{
    public static DataTemplate GetDataTemplateWithBindingByType(Type type, Binding binding)
    {
        var key = type.Name;

        DataTemplate template;
        switch (key)
        {
            case "String":
            {
                template = GetStringTemplate(binding);
            }
            break;
            case "Boolean":
            {
                template = GetBooleanTemplate(binding);
            }
            break;
            case "DateTime":
            {
                template = GetDateTimeTemplate(binding);
            }
            break;
            default:
                return null;
        }
        return template;
    }

    private static DataTemplate GetDateTimeTemplate(Binding binding)
    {
        DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate();
        FrameworkElementFactory factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(DatePicker));
        factory.SetValue(Control.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.CadetBlue);
        factory.SetBinding(DatePicker.SelectedDateProperty, binding);
        template.VisualTree = factory;
        return template;
    }

    private static DataTemplate GetBooleanTemplate(Binding binding)
    {
        DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate();
        FrameworkElementFactory factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(CheckBox));
        factory.SetValue(ContentControl.ContentProperty, "");
        factory.SetValue(Control.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Green);
        factory.SetBinding(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, binding);
        template.VisualTree = factory;
        return template;
    }

    private static DataTemplate GetStringTemplate(Binding binding)
    {
        DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate();
        FrameworkElementFactory factory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
        factory.SetValue(TextBlock.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Left);
        factory.SetValue(TextBlock.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Tomato);
        factory.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
        template.VisualTree = factory;
        return template;
    }
}
```

**How its looks like:**
[image: here]

**Update (added mappers)**

**Xaml code**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFAddGridViewColumnDynamicHelpAttempt.BindingTest"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:clr="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         xmlns:wpfAddGridViewColumnDynamicHelpAttempt="clr-namespace:WPFAddGridViewColumnDynamicHelpAttempt"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" x:Name="This">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <wpfAddGridViewColumnDynamicHelpAttempt:UpdatedViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<ListView x:Name="OuterListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ListView x:Name="InnerListView" ItemsSource="{Binding MappedObjects}">
                            <ListView.View>
                                <GridView wpfAddGridViewColumnDynamicHelpAttempt:GridViewColumns.HeaderTextMember="HeaderText"
                                          wpfAddGridViewColumnDynamicHelpAttempt:GridViewColumns.DisplayMemberMember="DisplayMember"
                                          wpfAddGridViewColumnDynamicHelpAttempt:GridViewColumns.ColumnTemplateKey="ColumnTemplateTemplateKey"
                                          wpfAddGridViewColumnDynamicHelpAttempt:GridViewColumns.ColumnsSource="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=DataContext.ColumnHeaders}">
                                </GridView>
                            </ListView.View>
                        </ListView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView></UserControl>
```

**ViewMOdel and mappers**

```
public class UpdatedViewModel:BaseObservableObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<ColumnDescriptor> ColumnHeaders 
    {
        get { return _columnHeaders; } 
        set
        {
            if (_columnHeaders == value)
                return;

            _columnHeaders = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => ColumnHeaders);
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MappedCollection<MappedObject>> Data
    {
        get { return _data; }
        set
        {
            if (_data == value)
                return;

            _data = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => Data);
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ColumnDescriptor> _columnHeaders;
    private ObservableCollection<MappedCollection<MappedObject>> _data;

    public UpdatedViewModel()
    {
        //ColumnHeaders = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        //ColumnHeaders.Add("String Column");
        //ColumnHeaders.Add("Boolean Column");

        ColumnHeaders = new ObservableCollection<ColumnDescriptor>
        {
            new ColumnDescriptor {HeaderText = "String Column", DisplayMember = "StringColumn", ColumnTemplateTemplateKey = typeof(String)},
            new ColumnDescriptor {HeaderText = "Bolean Column", DisplayMember = "BoleanColumn", ColumnTemplateTemplateKey = typeof(Boolean)},
        };

        Data = new ObservableCollection<MappedCollection<MappedObject>>();
        var mappedCollection = new MappedCollection<MappedObject>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            //row.Add("cell " + i);
            //row.Add(i % 2 == 0 ? true : false);
            mappedCollection.MappedObjects.Add(new MappedObject { StringColumn = string.Format("cell:{0}", i), BoleanColumn = i % 2 == 0 });

        }
        Data.Add(mappedCollection);
    }
}

public class MappedCollection<T>:BaseObservableObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<T> _mappedObjects;

    public MappedCollection()
    {
        MappedObjects = new ObservableCollection<T>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<T> MappedObjects
    {
        get { return _mappedObjects; }
        set
        {
            _mappedObjects = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

public class MappedObject:BaseObservableObject
{
    private object _stringColumn;
    private object _boleanColumn;

    public object StringColumn
    {
        get { return _stringColumn; }
        set
        {
            _stringColumn = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public object BoleanColumn
    {
        get { return _boleanColumn; }
        set
        {
            _boleanColumn = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

I'll glad to help if there will be problems with the code.

Regards.

Comment: your solution looks amazing and I really appreciate your help.  But there is still one little problem.  In my question, the elements in my data collection aren't made of a class, instead they are nested collection of primitive objects with INotifyPropertyChanged interface (therefore the two dimensional collection).    How can I map the elements in the nested collection to column descriptor collection (like you do with the Person class properties)?

Comment: @Kurorion can you please explain again why do you need that two dimensional  collection?

Comment: the data is provided to me by the backend programmer.  He would like to feed data from the database that can be of any type and number of rows/columns.  Some of the data can also be updated, therefore needing to be formatted based on the data type.  Basically the view needs to sets of data with varying type and columns without needing to update the view and viewmodel code.  But thinking about it, I believe I can make your solution work  as well.  I still haven't had time to try it out, been stuck on another project at the moment.  I will let you know!

Comment: I just tried your original solution and it works great. It also really helped me view the problem from another perspective.  The backend programmer and myself can definitely adapt it to our project.  Thanks again!