# WPF DataGrid flickering issue

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid

In WPF, I have a `DataGrid` bound to a `DataView` in the `ViewModel` class. It is a touch panel embedded project, so every time I touch and slide my fingers on the panel it keeps sending me values and saves those values to the `DataTable` and assigns it to the bound `DataView` in a way where it can show only 5 or 10 rows (predefined) as the data gets updated. Every time I get a new row I delete the last until the total `DataTable` row count is 5/10.

The issue here is that it is taking longer than usual for the `DataGrid` to bind to the last values. The moment I lift my hand off the panel, I expect the grid to bind to those values, but it is taking some 6 to 10 seconds to do this operation where the user has to wait for it to complete.

For this, I have used the `IsAsync` property in `XAML`. As expected, this makes the `DataGrid` bind fast but every time the data gets updated, the `DataGrid` flickers. How can I overcome the flickering issue in the `DataGrid`? Or is there any other way to do it. We are following MVVM patterns for the binding.

XAML:

```xml
<DataGrid
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=View, IsAsync=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    CanUserSortColumns="False"  
    CanUserResizeRows="False"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
    EnableColumnVirtualization="True" 
    EnableRowVirtualization="True"
    CanUserAddRows="False">

</DataGrid>
```

View Model:

```cs
private void InsertCollection(List<string> values)
{
    if (values == null || !values.Any()) return;

    try
    {
        var dataRow = ObjectMessageDataTable.NewRow();
        int columnCount = ObjectMessageDataTable.Columns.Count;

        var inputs = values.Select(y => y as object).ToArray();
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.Count() && i < columnCount; i++)
            dataRow[i] = values[i];

        ObjectMessageDataTable.Rows.InsertAt(dataRow, 0);
        var count = ObjectMessageDataTable.Rows.Count;

        while (count > NumOfRows)
        {
            ObjectMessageDataTable.Rows.RemoveAt(NumOfRows);
            count = ObjectMessageDataTable.Rows.Count;
        }

        ObjectMessageDataTable.AcceptChanges();
        View = ObjectMessageDataTable.DefaultView;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Without any code, that bounty is a waste of reputation. You should include a [mcve] if you want any helpful answers. There are plenty of ways of doing this but the specifics strongly depend on your current implementation. Unless you expect a generic answer that requires you to re-write everything you should share what you currently have.

Comment: you can see the sample code now

Comment: Can you share full code of datagrid xaml and collection binding? So can run and test.

Comment: You shouldn't have to add and delete rows if your are using MVVM patterns and implementing iNotifyPropertyChanged properly. Simply removing the values from your collection should update the DataGrid automatically. Can you post an example of your Model that is being used in this DataGrid?

Comment: This code looks dodgy on a number of levels. I'd suggest you rewrite it using an ObservableCollection<List<string>> rather than a DataView. Why do you need to cast the items in `values` as object?

Comment: @Tronald, am adding/removing the rows from the collection only not in the grid , FYI

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code. It is so simple to databind the datatable directly and the flickering will go away :). just use ObjectMessageDataTable.DefaultView instead of View. Because somehow the View object itself is created everytime View is created and this causes the datagrid to initialise from the beginning.

```
 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ObjectMessageDataTable.DefaultView, IsAsync=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

so change to

```
<DataGrid
        Grid.Row="1"
        Width="Auto"
        Height="Auto"
        Margin="0,20,0,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
        AlternatingRowBackground="WhiteSmoke"
        AlternationCount="2"
        AutoGenerateColumns="True"
        BorderBrush="Black"
        BorderThickness="1"
        CanUserAddRows="False"
        CanUserResizeRows="False"
        CanUserSortColumns="False"
        ColumnHeaderHeight="35"
        EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
        EnableRowVirtualization="True"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ObjectMessageDataTable.DefaultView, IsAsync=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        RowHeight="30"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19000003)

Comment: im trying to help another programmer.. if it is a big mistake, then i dont need ur reputation system!!! Thanks for your motivation to contribute !!!!!

Comment: Hi @nath, welcome to stackoverflow :), the comment you are seeing above is automatically generated when the answers are reviewed, the guy didn’t mean you no harm. Think about it, those rules when posting answers are what make stackoverflow so great, an answer is reviewed on different level to make sure that the person having the same issue in the future will always find the answer useful.

Comment: Hi Usama, thanks for ur kind words. Yes i understand and i also did with good intension but i understand :) thx a lot

Comment: @Csharp_crack, i hope it helps :)

Comment: @Csharp_crack can u give a feedback ?

Comment: @nath, no luck yet

Comment: Path=ObjectMessageDataTable.DefaultView ? with this it works for me in my test application

Comment: @nath, with that the filckering is gone but the data binding is slow which actually dumps my actually requirement. Its like not having IsAsync property at all.